# How to check each variable in the array, if the next element in the array is increasing?

Tags: java

I'm supposed to write a program that reads an array of ints and outputs the number of "triples" in the array.

A "triple" is three consecutive ints in increasing order differing by 1 (i.e. 3,4,5 is a triple, but 5,4,3 and 2,4,6 are not).

How do I check for the "triples"?

Current Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // put your code here
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[size];
        int iterator = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        } for(int j =0; j < size; j++){
            iterator++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried and the error/issue you are facing..

Comment: Use a for loop: `for(int k = 0; k < size-2; ++k){` and inside it check the next three numbers for consecutiveness.

Comment: I have posted code, that's all what I have tried since I don't know how to approach this problem.

Comment: May tripples overlap? i.e. does 1 2 3 4 count as one tripple or two?

Comment: yes,they may overlap.it counts as 2 triples.

Answer (score 1):

The following code loops through the entire array of integers. Inside of the loop it is checked if the third integer exists inside of the array (`(i + 2) < array.Length`) and the other 2 conditions are all about whether value1 is the same as the value2 decreased by 1 (`array[i] == array[i + 1] - 1` and `array[i + 1] == array[i + 2] - 1`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if((i + 2) < array.Length && array[i] == array[i + 1] - 1 && array[i + 1] == array[i + 2] - 1)
        System.out.println("Three values at indexes" + i + " " + (i + 1) + " and " + (i + 2) + " are a triple");
}
```

The code below is C# and sadly not compatible to Java that easily, I'll just leave that here for anyone who wants to know how its handled in C# (the `vt` variable is a so called `ValueTriple`):

```
(int, int, int) vt;
for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (i + 2 >= array.Length) continue;
    vt = (array[i], array[i + 1], array[i + 2]);
    if (vt.Item1 == vt.Item2 - 1 && vt.Item2 == vt.Item3 - 1)
        Console.WriteLine($"Three values at indexes {i}, {i + 1} and {i + 2} (Values: {array[i]}, {array[i + 1]}, {array[i + 2]}) are a triple");
}
```

Comment: Don't catch runtime exceptions like that, do a range check

Comment: Indeed, I'll change that asap. I got too used to try-catch lately

Comment: @MichaelA.Schaffrath well its c# code but those 2 don't differ much. I used to code java and kinda expected the exact same code to work. What exactly is the syntax error in this code, is it only the ValueTuple that does not exist in java?

Comment: I know it's C#. Just wanted to elaborate why this is not a helpful answer. The OP asked for help on his Java problem and you replied with a C# solution. And since the problem is rather simple, i'd guess that the OP is a beginner in programming and cannot be expected to 1. spot that it's not java 2. distill a syntax he is not familiar with into an abstract solution 3. apply this solution to his code

Comment: @MichaelA.Schaffrath i just edited my answer and now it should be valid Java Syntax. It's been quite a while tho since I've written my last Java code so feel free to point out errors since I will start writing some Java off-work soon again

Answer (score 0):

You may try following code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triplet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // put your code here
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[size];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        Integer counter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < size-2; i++) {
            if(array[i] == array[i+1] - 1 && array[i] == array[i+2] - 2) { //checking if three consecutive ints in increasing order differing by 1 
                counter++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }

}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

A method to find out the number of triplets could look like this. You then just have to call the method depending how your input is obtained and you wish to present the result.

```
public static int getNumberOfTriplets(int[] toBeChecked) {
    int numberOfTriplets = 0;
    int nextIndex = 0;
    while (nextIndex < toBeChecked.length - 2) {
        int first = toBeChecked[nextIndex];
        int second = toBeChecked[nextIndex + 1];
        int third = toBeChecked[nextIndex + 2];
        if ((first + 1 == second) && (second + 1 == third)) {
            numberOfTriplets++;
        }
        nextIndex++;
    }
    return numberOfTriplets;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of allowing the numbers to be in more than one triplet, the answer is fairly similar in how I would personally approach it:

```
//determines if the input sequence is consecutive
public boolean isConsecutive(int... values) {
    return IntStream.range(1, values.length)
            .allMatch(i -> values[i] == values[i - 1] + 1);
}

public int countTriples(int[] input, boolean uniques) {
    if (input.length < 3) {
        return 0;
    }
    int back = 0;
    for(int i = 2; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (isConsecutive(input[i - 2], input[i - 1], input [i]) {
            back++;
            if (uniques) { //whether to disallow overlapping numbers
                i += 2; //triple found, ignore the used numbers if needed
            }
        }
    }
    return back;
}
```

Then in calling it:

```
Int[] input = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8};
countTriples(input, true); //3
countTriples(input, false); //2
```